# How to add a space between dropdown and add to cart button in variable products

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce, for my variable products, How can I add a (gap) between woocommerce product page **"Choose an option"** button and "Quantity + Add to cart button"?

Here an explicit screenshot:

[image: click here to see the screen shot]

---

**Edit:** Here is a live link: http://www.noushasasart.com/product/harsh-bark/

Yes, I have moved the single "Add to cart" button just after the product title.

Comment: Please you should add a live link editing your question, as is not possible to answer it actually, giving you some minimal help.

Comment: Live link means to the website.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to be a customization that have been done here (that's why you get this problem): 
> The template **'single add to cart'** has been moved up to the **'short description'**.
>   Normally you should have a select dropdown field instead of the button **"Choose an option"**.

So you should try this:

```css
.single-product div.product .variations_button.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart {
    padding-top: 1em !important;
}
```

Or even more with: `padding-top: 2em !important;`

Or you can try to add some "top margin" too: `margin-top: 1em !important;`

> But not sure it will solve your problem as the only efficient way should be to have a live link.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, perfect